# Changing a bool to true/false with URLs in Django

Tags: python, django, boolean, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to change a specific primary key item such as 56, 60, or 75 bool's of "confirmed" to true with this code:

in models.py:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model): 
   confirmed = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)
```

in views.py:

```
def confirm(request, itemnum):
    item = get_object_or_404(PurchaseOrder, item_number = itemnum)
    convert_item = str(itemnum)
    PurchaseOrder.confirmed = True  # This is not working
    return HttpResponse('Item number '+ convert_item + ' changed to true' )
```

I am able to go the the URL such as /60/ but it will not change the bool to true.

Answer (score 4):

You should change the value of `confirmed` on the instance of your model and save it:

```
def confirm(request, itemnum):
    item = get_object_or_404(PurchaseOrder, item_number = itemnum)
    item.confirmed = True
    item.save()

    return HttpResponse('Item number %s changed to true' % itemnum )
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should be confirming your *item*; right now you are trying to confirm the entire `Purchase Order` class. Try:

```
def confirm(request, itemnum):
    item = get_object_or_404(PurchaseOrder, item_number = itemnum)
    convert_item = str(itemnum)
    item.confirmed = True  # confirm your item
    item.save()  # Have to save it first
    return HttpResponse('Item number '+ convert_item + ' changed to true' )
```